# Using Motorola NVG510 as wireless router via connecting it to Motorola SB5101 Cable Modem

Tags: wireless-networking, cable-modem, adsl-router, dsl-modem

I have a comcast cable connection at home. I have a Motorola SB5101U cable modem and Motorola NVG510. What I want to do is connecting the cable modem to the comcast cable and have internet access, and to connect the NVG510 modem through ethernet, then to have a wireless LAN at home that I can use to connect to internet.

SB5101 is a one-port ethernet and usb cable modem.

NVG is a 4-port ethernet wireless dsl modem.

When I connect the dsl modem to the cable modem, I simply can't access the internet, without knowing whether the modems can communicate (the dsl modem's admin page does present any related information, or I couldn't find otherwise).

I applied a suggested method which is setting the dsl modem's IPv4 address from the cable's modem's IPv4 address and DHCPv4 start and end addresses from the same address space (same address for both). This way I only can access to internet from one computer only if it is connected to the dsl modem via ethernet. On wireless I got no internet connection and I got an IP conflict error. Then I changed the DHCPv4 end address on the dsl modem and provided an IP interval for DHCP, this way I could connect multiple computers to the dsl modem through wireless or ethernet, but only one computer having an ethernet connection could access the internet.

This [is my question and the answer I got](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AlwUcN2NMPCfSJBvGqAaOy8azKIX;_ylv=3?qid=20130712232918AAE172a).

Is there some way I can't do what I want as described in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the NVG510's DHCP server and connect one of its LAN ports to the SB5101. You can also follow the instructions you got in the answer to your question on Yahoo which also seems correct.